# Receive binary data from a TCP server and save it to a file

Tags: erlang

How Does a TCP client receive binary data it requests from a TCP server?

If the server sends the requested data (some binary data at a certain position of  file) how is this received and saved to a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of connecting to a remote server, receiving data, and writing it to a file:

```
-module(recv).

-export([example/1]).

recv_data(IoDevice, Sock) ->
  case gen_tcp:recv(Sock, 0) of
    {ok, B} -> 
      ok = file:write(IoDevice, B),
      recv_data(IoDevice, Sock);
    {error, Reason} ->
      error_logger:info_msg("Done receiving data: ~p~n", [Reason]),
      file:close(IoDevice),
      gen_tcp:close(Sock)
  end.

example(FileName) ->
  {ok, IoDevice} = file:open(FileName, [write, binary]),
  {ok, Sock} = gen_tcp:connect("www.google.com", 80, [binary, {packet, raw}, {active, false}]),
  ok = gen_tcp:send(Sock, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"),
  recv_data(IoDevice, Sock).
```

This will connect to google and write the response to a file:

```
Erlang R14A (erts-5.8) [source] [smp:2:2] [rq:2] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.8  (abort with ^G)
1> c(recv).
{ok,recv}
2> recv:example("/tmp/test.bin").

=INFO REPORT==== 4-Nov-2010::08:52:59 ===
Done receiving data: closed
ok
3>
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to get data from the sender and store it. How would this line be different? ok = gen_tcp:send(Sock, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n") I am not sure why the second argument of gen_tcp:send is like that. The erlang docs say "some data", how can I choose what this some data is when it comes from the peer?

Comment: The data is received from the sender and stored in a file. The gen_tcp:send call is just to ask google.com, in this case, to send us data.

Comment: Thanks. What if I wanted to ask the uploader for a piece of data in a specific file?

Comment: Well, that would probably be a custom protocol. So you would have to design that yourself.

Answer (score 5):

You use [gen_tcp:recv](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#recv-2) to receive the data. A regular [write](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#write-2) can then save them to a file.